# (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

when running selenium in jupyter notebook along with beautifulsoup and pandas module for webscrapping this error occurs "
WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed. (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)".

Can someone help me solve it

i tried to run selenium. Here is the code:

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
PATH="D:\chromedriver.exe"
driver=webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get("https://www.amazon.in/dp/B06X9C2696?th=1")
```

here is the error log:

```
WebDriverException                        Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [487], in <cell line: 4>()
      2 from selenium import webdriver
      3 PATH="D:\chromedriver.exe"
----> 4 driver=webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
      5 driver.get("https://www.amazon.in/dp/B06X9C2696?th=1")

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py:81, in WebDriver.__init__(self, executable_path, port, options, service_args, desired_capabilities, service_log_path, chrome_options, service, keep_alive)
     78 if not service:
     79     service = Service(executable_path, port, service_args, service_log_path)
---> 81 super().__init__(
     82     DesiredCapabilities.CHROME["browserName"],
     83     "goog",
     84     port,
     85     options,
     86     service_args,
     87     desired_capabilities,
     88     service_log_path,
     89     service,
     90     keep_alive,
     91 )

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py:106, in ChromiumDriver.__init__(self, browser_name, vendor_prefix, port, options, service_args, desired_capabilities, service_log_path, service, keep_alive)
    103 self.service.start()
    105 try:
--> 106     super().__init__(
    107         command_executor=ChromiumRemoteConnection(
    108             remote_server_addr=self.service.service_url,
    109             browser_name=browser_name,
    110             vendor_prefix=vendor_prefix,
    111             keep_alive=keep_alive,
    112             ignore_proxy=_ignore_proxy,
    113         ),
    114         options=options,
    115     )
    116 except Exception:
    117     self.quit()

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py:288, in WebDriver.__init__(self, command_executor, desired_capabilities, browser_profile, proxy, keep_alive, file_detector, options)
    286 self._authenticator_id = None
    287 self.start_client()
--> 288 self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py:381, in WebDriver.start_session(self, capabilities, browser_profile)
    379 w3c_caps = _make_w3c_caps(capabilities)
    380 parameters = {"capabilities": w3c_caps}
--> 381 response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
    382 if "sessionId" not in response:
    383     response = response["value"]

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py:444, in WebDriver.execute(self, driver_command, params)
    442 response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
    443 if response:
--> 444     self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    445     response["value"] = self._unwrap_value(response.get("value", None))
    446     return response

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py:249, in ErrorHandler.check_response(self, response)
    247         alert_text = value["alert"].get("text")
    248     raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)  # type: ignore[call-arg]  # mypy is not smart enough here
--> 249 raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)

WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location C:\Users\ani\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    (No symbol) [0x0047F243]
    (No symbol) [0x00407FD1]
    (No symbol) [0x002FD04D]
    (No symbol) [0x0031C24E]
    (No symbol) [0x003182E9]
    (No symbol) [0x0034F056]
    (No symbol) [0x0034EB2A]
    (No symbol) [0x00348386]
    (No symbol) [0x0032163C]
    (No symbol) [0x0032269D]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00719A22+2655074]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0070CA24+2601828]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00528C0A+619850]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00527830+614768]
    (No symbol) [0x004105FC]
    (No symbol) [0x00415968]
    (No symbol) [0x00415A55]
    (No symbol) [0x0042051B]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x776200F9+25]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77DE7BBE+286]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77DE7B8E+238]
```

Comment: Instead of _administrator_ user execute the test as a regular user e.g. _testuser_

Comment: Also notice that the correct way to start the browser is `driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(PATH))` where Service is loaded with `from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service`

Comment: tried to run the solution. it didnt work